# Can someone explain to me the runtime of why Perfect Squares is O(sqrt(n))?

Tags: algorithm, runtime, big-o, perfect-square

> Problem

- Given a positive integer n, find the least number of perfect square numbers (for example, 1, 4, 9, 16, ...) which sum to n.

  Example 1:
  Input: n = 12
  Output: 3 
  Explanation: 12 = 4 + 4 + 4

  Example 2:
  Input: n = 13
  Output: 2
  Explanation: 13 = 4 + 9.

> Suggested Solution (BFS)

```
def numSquares(self, n):
    if n < 2:
        return n
    lst = []
    i = 1
    while i * i <= n:
        lst.append( i * i )
        i += 1
    cnt = 0
    toCheck = {n}
    while toCheck:
        cnt += 1
        temp = set()
        for x in toCheck:
            for y in lst:
                if x == y:
                    return cnt
                if x < y:
                    break
                temp.add(x-y)
        toCheck = temp

    return cnt
```

How does this particular BFS run in O(sqrt(n))? Because what I am thinking is finding squares take O(sqrt(n)). Because there are 2 for loops, (`for y in lst1` takes O(sqrt(n)), `for x in toCheck` takes O(sqrt(n)), shouldn't it be O(n)??

Comment: You probably need to memoize the results to reach O(sqrt(n)) complexity

Answer (score 2):

The running time is actually `Theta(n^(3/2))`. According to [Legendre's three-square theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_three-square_theorem), any integer of the form `4^a (8b + 7)` for integers `a` and `b` can be written as the sum of four squares but not three. Let `n` be an integer of this kind. There are `Omega(n)` numbers less than `n` that can be written as the sum of three squares, so in the final iteration of the while loop, `toCheck` has `Theta(n)` elements, and `lst` has `Theta(n^(1/2))`.

Comment: Beautiful. I was wondering if there was some theoretical result that would pop up here.